# WP_Query arguments order

Tags: wp-query, offsets

Given the following example of a custom query

```
$query = new WP_Query(array(
    'posts_per_page' => 7,
    'categor_name' => 'events',
    'offset' => 5
));
```

Does the order of arguments matter?

Will this query first select all posts with the given category and then offset the first 5 or will it first offset all 5 posts then select posts with given category?

Comment: possible typo `'category_name' => 'events',`

Answer (score 2):

The order doesn't matter. That query will get 7 posts from the "events" category, skipping over the 5 most recent (since the default order is by date).

Comment: Without the typo category order doesn't matter.